# how to log in telegram by sessions with the hash, without the id

Tags: session, telegram, telethon

I have the .session files and the hash but I don't have the account id, how can I log into the account or find out the id?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Neither the account ID, nor the api_id is required to log into the session file (provided it already contains a valid authorization). If you're talking about api_id and api_hash, those don't matter if you're already logged in. You can pass arbitrary values like so: `TelegramClient(session, api_id=1, api_hash="blabla")`